# Regular Expression in xpath for tables (PHP)

Tags: php, xpath

I need a regular expression for tables in which you get the contents of "thead/tr/td", tbody/tr/td, tbody/tr/td/span and tbody/tr/td/a. but not the images

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title1</th><th>Title2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Date1</td>
            <td><span>Date 2</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#">Date3</a></td>
            <td><img src="image.png"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I have tried with:

```
$selector = $xpath->query('//table')->item(0); 

$query1 = '/*[self::tbody or self::thead]/tr/[self::th or self::td][not(descendant::img)]/[self::* or self::a or self::span]';

$resultado1 = $xpath->query($query1,$selector);
```

Comment: Why do you say you want a regular expression? I can't see what role regular expressions might play in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select all `th|td` elements other than those whose sole content is an `img` element, or is empty, try

```
//*[self::td|self::th][node()[not(self::img)]]
```

If that's not exactly your requirement, you'll have to explain the requirement more clearly. E.g. what do you want to do if the `td` contains an `a|span` which itself contains an `img`, or if the `td` contains both an `a|span` and an `img` as siblings.